# Outlook - retrieve cid:attachment with different name

Tags: html, image, outlook, attachment

I've wrote a routine that converts .msg files to .pdf files doing this:

1. Saves and opens .msg files as Outlook.MailItem
2. Reads HTML body from MailItem, adds some Info (From, To, CC, Subject, Date, etc.) as header and turns it into PDF using 3d party library.

I was able to treat inline images attached and referenced by `cid:` tag, by converting them to Base64 strings and changing the `src=` attribute of the HTML accordingly.

However, recently I've got messages where `src="cid:..."` attribute contains a strange string instead of the name of the attachment. For instance:

```
<img border="0" width="459" height="146" id="_x0000_i1035" src="cid:_1_0C6B4BF40C6B47F8004BB5CF83258083" alt="Logo">
```

But the corresponding image comes attached as `Untitled attachment 00251.gif`

If I manually examine each case, I can deduce which attachment corresponds to each `<img>` tag, but how could I match these items inside my code? Has the `Attachment` object some property I could query for comparison with this strange string (**_1_0C6B4BF40C6B47F8004BB5CF83258083**)?

This is the code I've been using for matching:

```
Friend Shared Function SaveMsgAndAtt(ByVal message As MailItem) As String
    Dim filelist As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Dim html = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    html.LoadHtml(message.HTMLBody)
    Dim imgs = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]")
    Dim atts = message.Attachments.Cast(Of Attachment).ToArray
    Dim pairs = imgs.Select(
        Function(img) New With {
            .imageTag = img,
            .imageSrc = img.GetAttributeValue("src", ""),
            .imageAtt = atts.FirstOrDefault(
                Function(att) img.GetAttributeValue("src", "").Contains(att.FileName))}
            ).ToArray
    ''' Further processing
End Function
```